# Convert XML SOAP response to CSV

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, csv

I need some help with the following: I wrote a script to get a response from a webservice and then to save it in an XML file on my server. This is the structure of the XML file:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetCatalogResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetCatalogResult>
<Products>
<Product>
<Code>1234</Code>
<Name>product name</Name>
<Category>some category</Category>
<Manufacturer>manufacturer</Manufacturer>
<Price>100</Price>
<Stock>1</Stock>
</Product>
</Products>
</GetCatalogResult>
</GetCatalogResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using this script to convert the XML file to CSV:

```
$filexml='filename.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('filename.csv', 'w');

// I only need the CSV to contain two columns, the product code and the corresponding price

foreach($xml->Products->Product as $Product) {
$values = array("Code" => $Product->Code, "Price" => $Product->Price);
fputcsv($f, $values,',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
```

The problem is that there is no output in the CSV file, my guess is that there is a problem with the namespaces, but I can't get around it, even though I've read all the solutions given here to similar problems.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is here:

```
 $xml->Products->Product
```

Look at your xml structure, it's like this:

```
<soap:Body>
  <GetCatalogResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetCatalogResult>
      <Products>
        <Product>
```

`Products` is inside some node, you can't access it directly.

Comment: I know, I can't figure out how to access that particular node. Any idea on how to fix the problem? Thanks!

Comment: first of all convert "<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" to "<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? /> second use "$xml->soap:Envelope->soap:Body->GetCatalogResponse->GetCatalogResult->Products->Product" instead of "$xml->Products->Product".

Comment: I've already tried this option, but I get a PHP error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' in line 9 which is $xml->soap:Envelope->soap:Body->GetCatalogResponse->GetCatalogResult->Products->Product

Comment: Any other suggestions? Please :)

Comment: Late info but, for others that come looking, here is a solution with the namespace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022256/simplexml-soap-response-namespace-issues