# parse a SOAP XML response with Namespaces using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, namespaces, simplexml

I have this ugly XML which has alot of namespaces on it, when I try to load it with simpleXML if i indicate the first namespace I'd get an xml object ,but following tags with other namespaces would not make it to the object. 
Here is the SOAP response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns8502="http://tempuri.org">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <Interface PartnerID="FastBooking" PartnerType="Test" Version="1.0.0" />
     <Credentials HotelID="AC00006" User="User" Password="123456" />
     <Client Ref ="123456789" TimeStamp="2012-12-14T12:24:25+0100"/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <ServiceNameRQ xmlns="urn:wsTest">
         <GetRatesRS>
             <Rates>
                 <Rate RateID="12984" FromDate="2010-05-12" ToDate="2010-06-30" RateType="PUBLIC" RateCode="RAC" MinRate="100" MaxRate="1000" Currency="EUR" ReadOnly="No" FromRateID="11456">
                    <RateName>Rack Rate</RateName>
                 </Rate>
                 <Rate RateID="13219" FromDate="2010-07-12" ToDate="2010-12-31" RateType="PUBLIC" RateCode="NORMAL" MinRate="100" MaxRate="1000" Currency="EUR" ReadOnly="Yes">
                    <RateName>Normal Rate</RateName>
                     <R1 Name="Single Occupancy" MinRate="90.00" MaxRate="1500.00" />
                     <R2 Name="Double Occupancy" MinRate="120.00" MaxRate="2000.00" />
                     <R3 Name="2 Nights" MinRate="150.00" MaxRate="2000.00" />
                    </Rate>
                     </Rates>
            </GetRatesRS>
        </ServiceNameRQ>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the PHP code I'm using:

```
$result = $xml_query;
$result = stripslashes($result);

 $result = simplexml_load_string($result);
$namespacesMeta = $result->getNamespaces(true);
$mediaXML = $result->children($namespacesMeta['SOAP-ENV:Header']);

$Interface = $mediaXML->xpath('//Interface');
$Credentials = $mediaXML->xpath('//Credentials');
$Client = $mediaXML->xpath('//Client');

$attributesInterface = $Interface[0]['@attributes'];
$PartnerID = $attributesInterface['PartnerID'];
$PartnerType = $attributesInterface['PartnerType'];
$Version = $attributesInterface['Version'];

$attributesCredentials = $Credentials[0]['@attributes'];
$HotelID = $attributesCredentials['HotelID'];
$User = $attributesCredentials['User'];
$Password = $attributesCredentials['Password'];


$HotelID = filter_var($HotelID, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
$User = filter_var($User, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
$Password = filter_var($Password, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
$Password = tchag3iba($Password);
```

But I can not retrieve the contents of `SOAP-ENV:Body` (`GetRatesRS -> Rates -> Rate`)

Comment: Why are you running `stripslashes` on the XML response?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML SOAP response Namespace issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022256/simplexml-soap-response-namespace-issues) and this is basically manual material: [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.children), see *Example #2 Using namespaces*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rate data can be accessed like this:

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/m9Qpigkt)**

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($obj->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('urn:wsTest')->ServiceNameRQ->GetRatesRS->Rates->Rate as $rate)
{
    echo (string)$rate->RateName . "\n";
}
```

Outputs

> Rack Rate
>   Normal Rate

If you want the Rate attributes, you can get them like this (within the loop):

```
echo $rate->attributes()->RateID;
```

You can read the `R1` and `R2` elements like this:

```
foreach($obj->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('urn:wsTest')->ServiceNameRQ->GetRatesRS->Rates->Rate as $rate)
{
    if(isset($rate->R1))
    {
       echo $rate->R1->attributes()->Name;
       echo $rate->R1->attributes()->MinRate;
    }
    if(isset($rate->R2))
    {
       echo $rate->R2->attributes()->Name;
       echo $rate->R2->attributes()->MinRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Goldenkhattab see my edit for how to read R1 and R2, just repeat the same for R3, R4 etc etc