# Direct property assignment in php simple xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How to add a direct property assignment for tags with name space

eg .

if the tag is

```
<parent><child> My name is binbong</child></parent>
```

we can achieve this by

```
$parent->child =  My name is binbong
```

However if the tags are like this

```
<parent><name:blah:child> My name is binbong</child></parent>
```

How can use the direct assignment property ?

Comment: Post real examples, not some pseudo XML that you think looks the same. Additionally read about XML namespaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022256/simplexml-soap-response-namespace-issues